# What would the C++ equivalent be of rlwinm? (PowerPC)

Tags: c++, powerpc

I was reversing some old stuff of mine and came across an instruction I coulnd't quite understand. I'm rewriting it in C++ for easier readability.

The instruction:

```
rlwinm r4, r4, 2, 0, 29
```

Doing some research I came to the conclusion that this represents rotate left then and with mask. But since I'm quite new to C++, I can't seem to write it in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example what is getting rotated and where you are using the AND operation?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but from the manual it sort of seems like `r4 = (4*r4) & 0xfffffffc

Comment: I'd help you translate this to portable C++ if (and only if) you provided a link to documentation for that opcode and if you made a reasonable attempt yourself. Otherwise, this looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no direct language support for a rotate in C++, you need to use two shifts:

```
r4 = ((r4 << 2) | (r4 >> 30)) & 0x3FFFFFFF;
```

Some compilers have a rotate function, and the optimizer may recognize the two shifts as a rotate.  This assumes that `r4` is unsigned and 32 bits wide.  If it is signed you need to mask off the right shift.